# Equivalence and equality of a matrix and its diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, orthonormal

I have the following task:

Let $A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$. Find an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $P'=PA$ is symmetric. Corresponding, find an orthornormal matrix $Q$ (whose columns form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to the standard inner product) and a diagonal matrix $D$ s.t. $P'=Q^TDQ$

Until now I know that:

If I choose $P:= A^T$ then $PA$ is symmetric. But I don't see how $PA$ could equal to $Q^TDQ$, when I choose $Q$ as the identity matrix. Because if I choose Q as the identity matrix then I would have to prove that $PA$ = D. But this is impossible, right? Do I have to change my Q?

Comment: The task I'm trying to solve is to show that $P=Q^TDQ$. Where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix (columns form an orthonormal basis on $\mathbb{R}^4$) and D is a diagonal matrix. I'm trying to find such a $D$. As $Q$ I took the standard basis. Is that even possible?

Comment: I have just edited my question - sorry for the unclear questions before

Comment: The second sentence of your description of the task says “**Find** an orthonormal matrix $Q$...” This means that you can’t arbitrarily decide that $Q=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a theorem that any symmetric matrix $S$ is diagonalizable, i.e. we can find an invertible matrix $Q$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $S=Q^{-1}DQ$. Furthermore, when $S$ is symmetric, we can choose $Q$ to be orthogonal (same as orthonormal).

This certainly does not mean that $Q$ is the identity matrix. You should read up on how to diagonalise a matrix. There is a specific procedure involving eigenvectors. Take care to choose orthonormal eigenvectors in the process.

(For example, $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ is orthogonal but not the identity matrix.)

Comment: In my task I have that $Q^TDQ = P'$ instead of $Q^-1DQ$. That makes a difference right?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. An orthogonal matrix has the special property that $Q^T=Q^{-1}$.

Comment: That's a nice property. In that case I could diagonalise $P'$ and then find $Q$, right?

Comment: @speedy123 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Isn't it usually that $P'=QDQ^{-1}$ instead of $P'=Q^{-1}DQ$?

Comment: @speedy123 That is a matter of convention. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Can I use the Gram-Schmidt process to make the eigenvectors orthonormal to each other? Because I have found my eigenvectors and they‘re linearly independent to each other but just not orthonormal.

Comment: @speedy123 Yes.